# how to get this order by working in oracle pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, ora-00905

```
ORDER BY CASE
   WHEN v_SORT_TYPE = 'ASC' THEN
        CASE 
           WHEN v_SORT_ORDER = 'lname' THEN CAST(lname AS VARCHAR2(45)) || ',' || ROWNUM
           WHEN v_SORT_ORDER = 'code' THEN CAST(code AS VARCHAR2(52)) || ',' || ROWNUM
        END ASC
   WHEN v_SORT_TYPE = 'DSC' THEN
        CASE 
           WHEN v_SORT_ORDER = 'lname' THEN CAST(lname AS VARCHAR2(45)) || ',' || ROWNUM
           WHEN v_SORT_ORDER = 'code' THEN CAST(code AS VARCHAR2(52)) || ',' || ROWNUM
        END DESC                   
END
```

I am trying to write conditions for when v_SORT_TYPE is passed in as ASC or DSC. I am getting compilation error in this.

I assume this would be a common thing to do in my pl/sql SP's.

where am I going wrong?

Comment: What's the ORA error code?  And why are you concatenating ROWNUM to the end?

Comment: ROWNUM is concatenated to always get same rows back from oracle because we are doing pagination. error code is `ORA-00905`.

Comment: if the action is the same for both ASC and DSC why check for it?

Comment: sorry that is a typo....I've fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rethink the order by into multiple "columns".

```
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN v_sort_type = 'ASC' AND v_sort_order = 'lname' THEN lname END ASC,
  CASE WHEN v_sort_type = 'DESC' AND v_sort_order = 'lname' THEN lname END DESC,
  CASE WHEN v_sort_type = 'ASC' AND v_sort_order = 'code' THEN cname END ASC,
  CASE WHEN v_sort_type = 'DESC' AND v_sort_order = 'code' THEN cname END DESC
```

Only one of those would be in effect at any one time, so you'd effectively get (for example)

```
 ORDER BY null ASC,null DESC,code ASC, null DESC
```

or

```
 ORDER BY null ASC,lname DESC,null ASC, null DESC
```

Comment: Nice--that's definitely one to file away for future use.

Answer (score 1):

The alternative to a cut'n'pasted CASE() statement is to shape the query in-flight with dynamic SQL.

Here is the simplest demo possible.

```
create or replace function get_emps
    ( p_dno in emp.deptno%type
      , p_sort_col in varchar2 := 'EMPNO'
      , p_asc_desc in varchar2 := 'ASC')
    return sys_refcursor
is
    stmt varchar2(32767);
    return_value sys_refcursor;
begin

    stmt := 'select * from emp where deptno = :1';

    if p_sort_col is not null 
    then 
        stmt := stmt ||' order by '||p_sort_col||' '||p_asc_desc;
    end if;

    open return_value for stmt using p_dno;

    return return_value;

end get_emps;
/
```

And this is it in action ...

```
SQL> var rc refcursor
SQL> exec :rc := get_emps(20, 'ENAME')

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print rc

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 CLARKE     CLERK           7902 17-DEC-80        800                    20
      7902 GASPAROTTO ANALYST         7566 03-DEC-81       3000                    20
      7876 KULASH     CLERK           7788 23-MAY-87       1100                    20
      7788 RIGBY      ANALYST         7566 19-APR-87       3000                    20
      7566 ROBERTSON  MANAGER         7839 02-APR-81       2975                    20

SQL> exec :rc := get_emps(20, 'SAL', 'DESC')

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print rc

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7788 RIGBY      ANALYST         7566 19-APR-87       3000                    20
      7902 GASPAROTTO ANALYST         7566 03-DEC-81       3000                    20
      7566 ROBERTSON  MANAGER         7839 02-APR-81       2975                    20
      7876 KULASH     CLERK           7788 23-MAY-87       1100                    20
      7369 CLARKE     CLERK           7902 17-DEC-80        800                    20

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

ASC and DESC are keywords. CASE statements are going to evaluate to a value, not a keyword. One option would be dynamic SQL (build a string and then execute), another option would be to have an IF clause at a higher level. If you were only sorting by numbers, you could multiply by negative 1, but strings are tougher. I guess you could do something crazy like having a second table that stores strings and sort order as a number, and multiplying that number by -1, but I have a hard time believing that would be better in any conceivable way than the first two options.